# How to reference a 1 x 1 table entry as a parameter

Tags: powerquery

I have a table with column headers Alpha, Gamma, Delta, Beta.  I want to reorder the columns.  I have managed to separately create a table that has one row and and one column, holding the value "Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta" (including the double quotes).
So all I need to do is use the Table.ReorderColumns function, and somehow reference the "single cell" value as the columnOrder parameter.  I've tried numerous ways, (over numerous hours!), but no joy.
Can anybody point me in the right direction?
TIA, Colin

Answer (score 0):

Always the way.  Posted the question, then tried one more permutation and it worked!
I was overcomplicating it.  For the columnOrder parameter (of the Table.ReorderColumns function), I just needed to reference the single column in the helper table that - in my example - had 4 rows: Alpha, Beta, Gamma, Delta.  I was mistakenly continuing on from there to transpose and add the double quote wrappers.